# Provide steps for Cloud SQL(GCP) Database Restoration from automated Backups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

we have SQL Backup retention for 7 days, Here we have the backup of 7 days.
we followed the process of restoring from  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restoring.
I have created a new Postgres SQL instance with the same configuration as the running SQL Postgres instance.
I have selected the latest backup from automated Backups and restored it into a new SQL instance. When I connected one of the restored databases using PGAdmin data in a new backuped SQL Database and running SQL database are not the same i.e some data from tables are missing.
Please provide steps on how to recover full data from backups

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Database migration service](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration). Select your Azure database as source (you might require a public IP on your database, or set up a VPN to allow private communication), and then schedule a migration job.